# Trouble with SFP cables for a 10 Gb connection

Tags: cable, 10gbethernet

I have two machines, each with a 10 Gb adapter, directly connected with an SFP cable.  I purchased three SFP cables that look exactly alike (physically and specs), but only one works.  I'm having trouble finding clear information about SFP cables, so I appreciate the help in understanding the differences.

Here are the manfacturers, models, etc..

**10 Gigabit Card #1**: NetXen 3031

**10 Gigabit Card #2**: [QLogic QLE3142-CU-CK](http://www.qlogic.com/Products/ConvergedNetworking/IntelligentEthernetAdapters/Pages/QLE3142CU-CK.aspx)

**Cable #1 (the one that works)** [AIPC 7M](http://www.amphenol-aipc.com/images/sfp+copper.pdf)

**Cable #2 (no good)** [Blade Networks
BN-SP-CBL-1M](http://www.bladenetwork.net/SFP-Cable.html)

**Cable #3 (no good)** [Cisco SFP-H10GB-CU3M](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/prod/collateral/modules/ps5455/data_sheet_c78-455693.html)

I can't even get link lights with the two "no good" cables.  I will be ordering a few more of the AIPC cables since they work of course, but I'd like to get a decent understanding of why one works, but not the other.  Cable length?  Active vs. passive?  Different versions/revisions?

Comment: Are the pinouts the same on all three cables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After switching to Intel 10 GbE cards on both sides, the cable issues have disappeared!  We also had trouble with overheating on those QLogic cards, so I recommend going with Intel.

We are using the [Intel® 82599EB 10 Gigabit Ethernet Controller](http://ark.intel.com/Product.aspx?id=32207).

Answer (score 0):

I'm having a problem with a similar configuration, however I don't have another cable to test with.

The cards I'm using are both the same, Dell Part Numbers T645H, Intel Models 82598.

The cable I'm using between the cards is a Cisco SFP-H10GB-CU3M.

I found this information helpful from Intel.com regarding which SFP+ cables will work with that card: http://www.intel.com/support/network/adapter/10gbe/afdadualserver/sb/CS-029097.htm

It mentions the cables have to comply with certain specifications to function properly, and according to the product page for the cable I have, they match and should be working.

Cisco cable details: http://www.cisco.com/en/US/prod/collateral/modules/ps5455/data_sheet_c78-455693.html

I saw this relatively cheap switch on eBay, (Item number: [370424159424](http://cgi.ebay.com.au/ws/eBayISAPI.dll?ViewItem&item=370424159424&ru=http%3A%2F%2Fshop.ebay.com.au%3A80%2F%3F_from%3DR40%26_trksid%3Dm570%26_nkw%3D370424159424%26_sacat%3DSee-All-Categories%26_fvi%3D1&_rdc=1))
and considered buying that to see if it has to do with it not being a 'crossover' cable per se.

I'm hesitant to do that since the description mentions it having SFP ports, rather than SFP+ ports, and I'm unsure they're the same, or if they're compatible. This is my first foray into 10GB-land, and I'm early in the learning curve.

Does anyone have some good news for us on this?

Comment: I've turned your URLs into links, but there's really two parts to your post - the first half is appropriate as an answer as it links to specs, but the 2nd half, asking about if the eBay product is appropriate, should really be a question on its own so that you can collect your own responses to it. Feel free to click the "Ask a Question" button in the top-right corner and re-post as a question.

Comment: I'm also going to be trying a 10Gb switch to see if it helps with the connection problems.  I'll let you know how it goes.

Comment: Banjer, have a look here at the question I posted, in case the answers may be relevant.
aich_tee_tee_peah://serverfault.com/questions/176017/nic-status-stays-at-network-cable-unplugged-although-cable-is-present